# OpenVPN clients cannot reach LAN machines

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm using https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn to setup an OpenVPN server on my LAN server (`192.168.2.10`) which is behind a router (`192.168.2.1`) with several other machines (`192.168.2.11`, `192.168.2.12`, etc.). This OpenVPN container uses the host network directly (`--network host`) to ease routing configuration.

**The problem:** I'd like VPN clients to be able to reach these `192.168.2.0/24` machines and vice versa.

The OpenVPN server is on the `192.168.255.0/24` subnet. It pushes this route to VPN clients through the OpenVPN configuration:

```
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

But from a VPN client (`192.168.255.20`) I can only:

- `ping 192.168.2.10` which is the OpenVPN server IP on the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet
- `ping 192.168.255.1` which is the OpenVPN server IP on the `192.168.255.0/24` subnet

**And cannot ping `192.168.2.1`, `192.168.2.11` or `192.168.2.12`.** But from the OpenVPN server container, I can.

I'm not a network expert so I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something here, but what?

Answer (score 1):

Your other machines need the *opposite* route for reaching VPN clients through the OpenVPN server. (Ordinary packet routing is stateless, so just because you have the correct routes for *sending* a ping doesn't mean the recipient is always able to *reply* back to you – it cannot "piggy-back" on the original request.)

Add a route for network `192.168.255.0/24` via `192.168.2.10` to your LAN router (.2.1).

Optionally, you could also add the same route to each individual LAN device, or even distribute that route via DHCP (using the "classless static routes" DHCP option).

---

If the LAN router absolutely doesn't support static route configuration, a common alternative is to enable SNAT on the OpenVPN server's firewall – make it masquerade all packets from VPN clients as if they were actually from 192.168.2.10 (the VPN server itself).

This will allow LAN hosts to reply back (because they think they're replying to another local LAN device), but it won't allow them to initiate new connections *to* VPN clients. (Unless you add "port forwarding" DNAT rules...)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I added the route to my router (EdgeRouter X-SFP) but it didn't solve the problem. What tools should I use to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Use tcpdump, or other packet capture tools.